# typeScript+ vue+property decorator : prop default value type

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-i18n

**Hello**,

I have a **prop** like this ,

and I have **type error** when I want to **translate** text using **i18n**

```
  @Prop({
default: function() {
  return [
    {
 >     text: this.$t('wawi_id'),
      align: 'start',
      sortable: false,
      value: 'id'
    },
    { text: 'Name', value: 'name' },
  
  ]
}
})
```

This is **error** i get from **typescript**

```
 Property '$t' does not exist on type 'PropOptions<any> | Constructor | Constructor[]'.
  Property '$t' does not exist on type 'PropOptions<any>'.Vetur(2339)
```

**How** can  fix this ??

Answer (score 0):

You are not using `this` keyword correctly. Try this:

```js
text: this.$i18n.t("wawi_id"),
```